# Запись в лог-файл определённой информации (не всего подряд)

Tags: bash, telegram, логирование, файловый-ввод-вывод

Есть такой скрипт для получения статуса пользователя через Telegram CLI:

```
#!/bin/bash
name=$1
path=/home/user/tg
LOGFILE="/home/user/Bot/tg.log"
/home/user/bin/telegram-cli -k ${path}/tg-server.pub -W -e "user_info $name >> ${LOGFILE}"
exit 0
```

Я хочу записать в LOGFILE полученную информацию, то есть результат запроса

```
user_info $name
```

Сам результат выглядит примерно так:

> @user (#id......):
>
> phone: 7123456789
>
> offline (was online [2021/03/31 14:50:50])

Но в файл помимо статуса записывается ненужная информация (приветственное сообщение и прочее) да ещё и в виде кракозябр.
Как записать в файл только эти три строчки?

Файл с кракозябрами: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrGhd.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте постобработку полученных строк с помощью `grep` для отбора только нужных вам строк.

```
/home/user/bin/telegram-cli -k ${path}/tg-server.pub -W -e "user_info $name" | grep -E '^(@user|phone|offline)' >> ${LOGFILE}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Странное дело, когда я выполняю эту команду без вывода в файл, в терминал выводятся три нужные строчки. Но когда я добавляю `>> ${LOGFILE}` в начале файла всё равно выводятся кракозябры (хотя и не так много), а последние три строки - то что нужно.

Comment: Кстати, я осуществляю поиск чуток по-другому: `grep -E '(@|phone|offline)'` Но ведь не из-за этого в файл записывается мусор?

Comment: @Светлана, с таким шаблоном, как у вас, в вывод будут попадать строки, в которых есть указанные значения в любых местах, а  а моем варианте - только вначале строк.

Comment: @Светлана, попробуйте писать логи в отдельный файл `>> /tmp/foo.txt`. У меня подозрение, что в указанный вами файл еще какой-то процесс пишет

Comment: Да, я просто не очень точно описала шаблон вывода. Если точнее, он выглядит так:
User First Last @user (#id.......):
<новая строка и табуляция>phone: 7123456789
<новая строка и табуляция>offline (was online [2021/03/31 16:06:40])
А в выводе есть другие строки, начинающиеся с User. Поэтому мне проще указать собаку, но она не в начале строки.

Comment: Указала вывод в несуществующий файл с перезаписью: `> 1`, всё равно кракозябры.

Comment: @Светлана, а кракозябры это не управляющие  последовательности ANSI часом? приведите кусок таких кракозябр - обновите вопрос

Comment: Добавила ссылкой, так как скриншот громоздкий, ничего? После добавления `grep` файл стал таким https://i2.paste.pics/7a899be54c33a83c17e92d31cb8abe39.png

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122502/discussion-between-jigius-and-).